# Tkinter messagebox not behaving like a modal dialog

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

I am using messagebox for a simple yes/no question but that question should not be avoided so I want to make it unavoidable and it seems if I have one question box.

```
messagebox.askyesno("text", "question?")
```

Then I can go back to the root window of tkinter with the question still waitng for response, but if I have

```
messagebox.askyesno("text", "question?")
messagebox.askyesno("text", "question?")
```

With the first messagebox open I can still go back to the root window of tkinter but with the other questionbox I am unable to ( like I need). This applies to every messagebox I tested. Can anybody explain me why that is and how can I make the first question box unavoidable or I just have to do a blank `messagebox` before my actual question box. Is there anything I am doing wrong, because I think message box should not care if there has been a message box before it.

To illustrate my point better, I started to put together a simple nicely organised example, and it worked perfectly. I figured out what were the differences, as I started to use `messagebox` for the first time, I wanted to test its capabilities, and did not put it in a function. In a function it works perfectly.

Comment: `tkinter.messagebox.askyesno` already produces a modal dialog as you want.

Comment: The dialog should be modal, so it would be useful to see a bit more code to better understand the context.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I know that dialog produces a model dialog but the user can still ignore the question and go back to the root window. For example if you try to save a file in windows op and you already have a file with same name you get error message with cannot be avoided ( starts beeping and stuff). Thats what I want. As said before that excat action happens with second messagebox (and third, forth and so on) after first messagebox has been answered.

Comment: could you provide a complete *minimal* example that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @user1362446 You should provide your solution as an answer and accept it once it's allowed (after a few days).

Comment: You can use wait_window with grab_set (something like http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/ModalWindow ), or withdraw/iconify the root until the 2nd window closes.  Just noticed that this is from 2012 -- Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Use `grab_set`to keep the focus off root until the messagebox has been answered. Alternatively call `wait_window()` after opening the messagebox. Only need 1 or the other

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.messagebox import askyesno

def onClick():
    root.grab_set() # Prevent clicking root while messagebox is open
    ans = askyesno('Confirm', 'Press Yes / No')
    root.wait_window() # Prevent clicking root while messagebox is open
    if ans:
        print('Yes Pressed')
    else:
        print('No Pressed')

root = tk.Tk()

tk.Button(root, text='Click me', command=onClick).pack()

root.mainloop()
```