# How can i create a Modal Dialogue Box by messagebox.showerror

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

How can I create a Modal Dialogue Box by messagebox.showerror?

```
messagebox.showerror("Error", "No downloader.exe found")
```

When I create a messagebox, I found I can move the root windows.
and i need to create a Modal Dialogue Box like filedialog.askopenfilename.

```
filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = self.get_path()+ '/bin', filetypes=[("BIN Files", ".bin")])
```

here's the codes:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import os

class Application(Frame):

    def createWidgets(self, main_frame):

        #self.llabel = Label(main_frame, text="Ready", width=20, bg="turquoise", font = ftLabel)
        #self.llabel.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E) #columnspan=2

        self.frame1 = Frame(main_frame)
        self.frame1.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky=W+E+N+S)

        self.addr = StringVar()
        self.addrtext = Entry(self.frame1, width=20, textvariable = self.addr)
        self.addrtext.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W+E+N+S)
        self.addr.set("0x0")

        self.bfile = Button(self.frame1, text='BIN File', width=20)
        self.bfile.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=W+E+N+S)

        messagebox.showerror("Error", "No downloader.exe found")

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        main_frame = Frame(master)
        main_frame.pack(fill="y", expand=1)
        self.createWidgets(main_frame)
        self.dl_thread = 0


if __name__=="__main__":

    root = Tk()

    #lock the root size
    root.resizable(False,False)

    app = Application(master=root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and `messagebox.showerror` is modal to me.

Maybe there is something else in your code (threads?) or maybe it's 
dependent on your environment.

For reference, my entire code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox          

root = Tk()
def do(): messagebox.showerror("Error", "No downloader.exe found")

b = Button(root, text='Dialog', command=do)
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

If that doesn't work you might want to take a look at: [Tkinter messagebox not behaving like a modal dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12865392/tkinter-messagebox-not-behaving-like-a-modal-dialog/33962169)

Comment: thank's for replay. I update the codes in question please check. I call messagebox.showerror in createWidgets when init the class Application. And you can still move/close the main Frame while messagebox showing

Comment: You're right, the problem is about threads. We need to open the messagebox in another thread...